VSC gradle environment variables
Do you know why environment variables doesn't work with Gradle for java extension ? There is no way to set them in e.g. launch.json or settings.json files. Gradle Version: 8.10.2. VSC Version: 1.96.0 (Universal)
VSC is always reporting null attached to the environment variable e.g:
build.gradle
ext.gitea_protocol = System.getenv("GITEA_PROTOCOL")
println "protocol: ${gitea_protocol}"

VSC -> output
protocol: null
The same configuration works perfectly fine for Gitea actions.
I have try many different ways of setting env variables in e.g:
launch.json
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Launch Current File",
    "request": "launch",
    "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
    "mainClass": "${file}",
    "envFile": "${workspaceFolder}/.env",
    "env": {
        "GITEA_PROTOCOL": "http",
        "GITEA_URL": "git.lab:3000",
        "gitea_protocol": "http",
        "gitea_url": "git.lab:3000",
        "protocol": "http",
        "url": "git.lab:3000"
    }
},
{
    "type": "java",
    "name": "Run Gradle Task",
    "request": "launch",
    "mainClass": "",
    "projectName": "service",
    "args": [
        "build",
        "init"
    ],
    "vmArgs": [
        "GITEA_PROTOCOL=http",
        "gitea_protocol=http",
        "protocol=http",
    ]
}

or in .env file:
GITEA_URL=git.lab:3000
GITEA_PROTOCOL=http
or in settings.json:
"java.configuration.runtimes": [
    {
        "GITEA_PROTOCOL": "http",
        "protocol": "http"
    }
]

I expect the environment variables will be set before executing the gradle build file in VSC and the values will be set for repositories definition in build.gradle e.g:
maven {
    name = "Gitea"
    url "${gitea_protocol}://${gitea_url}/api/packages/Registry/maven"
    allowInsecureProtocol = true
}

I expect it will be working exactly the same way it is working in Gitea Actions or Github Actions.
